# How to format a string date in another format?

Tags: php, date

A date is stored in my database like so:

```
2011-11-22 15:14:27
```

Is there a way to format it so it comes out like:

```
22nd November 2011
```

Thanks

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: See PHPs [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and [strptime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php echo date('jS F Y',strtotime($dateVar)); ?>
```

See: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

so you are mor flexible wih the format

```
function convertTime($time = FALSE, $to = FALSE){
    if(!$to) $to ='jS F Y';
    return date($to, strtotime($time));
}
```

Comment: ok, already postet as normal... not fast enough ^^